# what is the use of space invader operator in python?

Tags: python, operators

How to explain this code to my students ?

```
>>> x = 42
>>> x -=- 1
>>> x
43
```

Acually who invent this space invader operator and for what ?

Comment: `x -=- 1` == `x -= (-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-=-` is not an operator in Python. It is two operators. Look at your expression:

```
x -=- 1
```

Let's rearrange the spacing a bit:

```
x -= -1
```

This looks more like what is actually happening. The `-=` operator is the [*subtraction assignment* operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/subtraction_assignment.html). Basically, `a -= b` is a shortcut for `a = a - b`.

The second `-` is the [*unary minus* operator](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/unary.html). It makes the `1` negative.

So what you are getting is equivalent to:

```
x = x - (-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`x -=- 1` is adding 1 to `x` (subtraction of a negative number is the same as addition of a positive number), so it will do the same thing as `x += 1`

Comment: what this the use of it ?